# How to ensure type in dynamic inheritance

Tags: c#-3.0

I have the following code:

```
public abstract class A //(a)
    {
            public dynamic Id { get; set; }

    }

  public class B: A
    {
       ...     
    }


    public class C:A
    {
         ...   
    }
```

How can I make it so that B.Id is an int and C.Id is always a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public abstract class A<T> //(a)
{
        public T Id { get; set; }

}

public class B: A<int>
{
   ...     
}


public class C:A<String>
{
     ...   
}
```